# How to set up a build and test pipeline for ASP.NET Core Web Application with Angular on Gitlab?

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, gitlab-ci

I am trying to write a .gitlab-ci.yml file for ASP.NET Core Web Application with Angular using docker image mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2

The build fails with an error stating that nodejs is missing.
The project requires node to download dependencies and build the Angular application embedded in it.

*.gitlab-ci.yml*

```
image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2

stages:
    - build
    - test

variables:
    test: "testcases"

before_script:
    - "cd src"
    - "dotnet restore"
build:
    stage: build
    script:
        - "dotnet build"

test:
    stage: test
    script: 
        - "cd $test"
        - "dotnet test"
```

Answer (score 5):

Worked!
Just installed node and angular CLI before performing the build.

**.gitlab-ci.yml**

```
image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2

stages:
    - build
    - test

variables:
    test: "testcases"

before_script:
    - "dotnet --info"
    - "curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | bash -"
    - "apt-get install -y nodejs"
    - "npm install -g @angular/cli"
build:
    stage: build
    script:
        - "cd src"
        - "dotnet build"

test:
    stage: test
    script: 
        - "cd $test"
        - "dotnet test"
```